# Only show own comments in admin panel

Tags: comments

My website is a community blog! On the WordPress dashboard > comment I would like to show only the current user's comments. Other users' comments should be hidden and only visible for admins.

[image: All User comment!]

Any function for it?

Comment: My website is a community blog!! On wordpress dashboard > comment I would like to show only his comment. Other user's comment should be hidden and visible for admin. Any function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below should do the trick, just add to your `functions.php` file.

```php
/**
 * Prevent non-administrator users from viewing others comments.
 */
add_filter( 'comments_list_table_query_args', function( $args ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit-comments.php' ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $value = !empty( $args[ 'author__in' ] ) ? $args[ 'author__in' ] : [];

        if ( is_array( $value ) && !in_array( $user->ID, $value ) && !in_array( 'administrator', (array)$user->roles ) ) {
            $value[] = $user->ID;
        }

        $args[ 'author__in' ] = $value;
    }

    return $args;

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

I was able to put this together by viewing the code of `wp-admin/edit-comments.php`. Within the file I found a call to the class `WP_Comments_List_Table` (found in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php`) which extends the `WP_List_Table` class.

From experience I knew the `WP_List_Table` requires a method `prepare_items()` which usually handles the query. In here I found the filter [`comments_list_table_query_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_list_table_query_args/) which allows us to modify the query arguments before the comments query is made.

Comment: Thank You so much! This function works for me ! But comment count issue!! Can you please write an extra function to fix comment count for me!!